# CMake not found, yet it is installed

Tags: centos, software-installation, cmake

I am attempting to install CMake in a cluster environment running Centos 7.2, by executing:

```
./bootstrap --prefix=/home/user/opt
  make      
  make install
```

Compiling doesn't give any errors, yet, `cmake --version` shows it is not installed. 
However,  `/home/user/opt/bin/cmake -version` gives me:

```
3.5.2
CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
```

Moreover, when I try to install gflags via `export CXXFLAGS="-fPIC" && cmake .. && make VERBOSE=1`, I again get `-bash: cmake: command not found`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is `/home/user/opt/bin/` in your `PATH`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `/home/user/opt/bin/` to your PATH variable.  e.g.:

```
PATH="$PATH:/home/user/opt/bin/"
```